# React routes with two parameters not working on react build

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router and everything works fine in development, but the production build of the react app is not working when I visit some routes with more than one parameter for example http://localhost:3000/me/edit.

I tried deploying in netlify with the _redirects file, also with nginx and also with serve. None of the three options worked.

It seems to be requesting a file inside the static folder. I will attach two images so you can see what I'm refering to.

This is what I can see under Sources tab:

When I visit http://localhost:3000/me it works fine and this is what I can see on chrome:
[image]

When I visit http://localhost:3000/me/edit if leads to a blank page, and it seems to be requesting a file inside me > static > edit which obviously does not exist; and this is what I can see on chrome:
[image]

Comment: How are you generating the edit page? If it doesn't exist then netlify is not a valid option, since it's a hosting for static files. That is indeed why it's looking inside the static folder.

Comment: Hey Nicolas! It's just a component that allows the user logged in to edit his/her profile. When you log in you are redirected to `localhost:3000/me` , in this page you have a button to edit your profile, if you press it then you are redirected to `localhost:3000/me/edit` and everything works fine, now if you reload the page, this error happens.

Comment: Does the page edit exist? That was my point, if it doesn't then netlify won't be enough. Static hostings need all the pages generated, that is why they are usually faster.

Comment: Yes, I can visit the page if I click the button that redirects you to that page /me/edit but for example if I paste the link here http://localhost:3000/me/edit and I click it, it will load a blank page

Comment: Are you using Webpack in your project?

Comment: Hey Beyond! Nope, I didn't configure Webpack. The app is created using create-react-app

Comment: What about the order of the route definitions?

Comment: Solved it! Express saved my life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I could finally solve this, the problem was that routes with more than one parameter either static or dynamic (eg: `/me/edit` or `/user/:id`) were looking for a file inside a folder, in this case `me` or `user` which do not exist.
Here's how I solved it:

I created a folder called 'production' inside this folder I ran npm init, I pasted the entire `build` folder generated by react. Then I created a file called `server.js` (which is the entry point I specified). This file contains the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors')

// Initializing express
const app = express()

// Initializing middleware to indicate express where to serve the static files from:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });

app.use(cors())


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT} `))
```

In addition, I added this: `<base href="/">` to my index.html file inside the build folder.

On the package.json I added the start script `"start": "node server.js"` and that's it, never was typing npm start so satisfactory

The entire project now looks like this:

[image]